# I got error when I submit with django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to post data from 2 django forms but I can't save data to my db.
Why is it? After I pushed submit button, I see message "it is required" below my price input box.

My views

```
def addproduct(request):

   user = request.user
   product_form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
   product_image_form = ProductImageForm(request.POST or None)

   if product_form.is_valid() and product_image_form.is_valid():
      product = product_form.save(commit=False)
      product.user = request.user
      product.slug = slugify(product_form.cleaned_data['title'])
      product.featured = False
      product.active = False
      product.save()
      product_image = product_image_form.save(commit=False)
      product_image.featured = False
      product_image.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/%s'%(product.slug))
```

My Models

```
class Product(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
   price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=100, default=0)
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')
   featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My forms

```
from django import forms
from .models import Product, ProductImage

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Product
       fields = ('title', 'description', 'price')

class ProductImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = ProductImage
       fields = ('image', 'featured')
```

Comment: You will need to provide your template code. All Django form fields are required *by default* unless you explicitly declare `blank=True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get "This field is required" error not below the price input box but above image selector.  You forget to pass `request.FILES` argument to the `ProductImageForm`:

```
product_image_form = ProductImageForm(request.POST or None,
                                      request.FILES or None)
```

And don't forget to specify `enctype` attribute in your `<form>` tag:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks catavaran! But I have another error "column slug is not unique" this time. I check slug field and I an see the sotred slug data but and it is unique. Do i misunderstand something?

Comment: You have product with the same slug in the database.  You should check it before saving the `product` and alter the slug to be unique.  `django-autoslug` module may help you.

Comment: Oh, great!. endless error coming. this time "myproducts_productimage.product_id may not be NULL". why is it?

Comment: You might want to do some research and if you can't figure out what's going wrong please ask a new question.

Comment: You forget to assign `product_image.product = product`

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot catavaran. Now I feel the power of stackoverflow.